# Why is my Kibana dashboard field showing as $metric.value?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

what i'm trying to find out, what could be the problem leading to this field showing as $metric.value in Kibana? Does someone bumped into a similar problem with Kibana Dashboard? Thanks[image: ![Kibana Dashboard]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g82cG.png)

Comment: Check your index, dos it have a field `$metric.value` ?

Comment: Hello thx for answering, I found the problem, when sending a null String to a field the field is becoming $metric.value, if you send an empty String instead, everything looks ok.